# What does this notation mean: $A^{T}A\in S_{+}^{n}$

Tags: matrices, notation

I was wondering what the following notation which I had encountered in my textbook means:

> $A^{T}A\in S_{+}^{n}$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

Comment: Doesn't your textbook have a definition of $S_+^n$ ?

Comment: The textbook was made my professor, but I am not sure if this symbol means that the matrix is symmetric. If so is this notation widely used? @coffeemath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S^n_+$ denote the set of positive semidefinite matrices, i.e., the set of real symmetric matrices having nonnegative eigenvalues.